# Doing Some Different Commands in Notepad++ in a One Command Line in Order Way

Tags: regex, notepad++

Consider we want to do some changing in a text file in order.

For example, we want to first replace "+" with "," and after that remove "^" from the text.

By *in order expression*, I mean, 
at first we do replacing "+" and then remove "^".

*My question:* Is there a way in the *regex* in Notepad++ that can be used to do these two commands in a one command-line?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: I don't see any conflicts if latter applies first. What's the reason behind it?

Comment: @revo It was an example that I made it. I have a text file that I need to do some action in order way and because of this I made this post.

Comment: Could you show some examples and expected result? Is the caret `^` appearing once or more times and is it at the beginning, the end or anywhere in the string?

Comment: @Toto one example that i have is this: consider we have two symbols "+c" and "c". I want to replace "+c" to "," and "c" to "0,". Therefore I should first replace "+c" and after that the second one. "^" can appear more times especially in this cases "+^" and "+ ^".

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51544497/edit) and add some input lines and expected result.

Comment: @Toto OK I edit it based on the comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with a regex like this:

```
(.*?)\+(.*?)\^
```

And this replacement string:

```
$1,$2
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vf5J3J/1)**

Comment: Is it possible to ask you to explain more. I cant get it. you know I am a math student and I am beginner to work with notepad++.

Comment: @user0410 the regex looks difficult but it's quite simple actually. I just search all before the `+`, then `+` and then search all before the `^`. So, the trick comes in the replacement string. Both "search all" patterns are captured in capturing groups, so in the replacement string I bring back the captured content. Take a look at this diagram [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/gRSpJayCm4q7On_y)

Comment: I got it.  I appreciate you for your useful diagram. You answer as a teacher. Thanks